# Email user on install or new gmail account creation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm toying with an extension that interacts with Gmail, and am interested in auto-generating a "Welcome" email with setup instructions on install or when a new Gmail account is created with the extension already installed.

For some background, *HelloSign for Gmail* seems to do this, and is where the inspiration comes from. With the extension already installed, upon creating a new Gmail address, HelloSign sent me a "Setup Instructions" email almost immediately (Screenshot of email: http://screencast.com/t/C3v7hL1Chr). I have had the extension installed for quite some time, and don't recall receiving this email when I initially installed it, but may have just overlooked it at the time.

I'm not sure if there is a command built into the extension to generate this, or if they're just extracting the email address signed into Gmail and generating it on their own. I know the getAuthToken API will pull in data for the user signed into Chrome, but I can't find anything like this for Gmail.

I'm very new to all of this and the answer may be right in front of me, but I haven't been able to find it. Any input is greatly appreciated!